# Generate list of range tuples with given boundaries in python

Tags: python, list, range, tuples

[edit] I'm not sure if this better off to codereview, if so, please migrate :) thanks!

So we were sitting here, working on a semi-academic problem.

Given a `start`, `stop` and `step`, generate a list of range tuples, so that

```
gen_range(100, 140, 10)
```

would produce

```
[(100, 110), (110, 120), (120, 130), (130, 140)]
```

also, given then fact that it should work on, say, iterating 500M integers with a step of 100 and not take forever.

The implementation I've come up with is as follows:

```
def gen_range(start, stop, step):
    llist = range(start, stop+step, step)
    batch_list = []

    if llist[-1] > stop:
        llist[-1] = stop

    for a, b in enumerate(llist[:-1]):
        batch_list.append((llist[a], llist[a+1]))

    print batch_list

gen_range(100000000,600000000,100)
```

But I can't stop thinking that it can be done in a more efficient (also code-length wise) way. Any suggestions?

[edit]

One thing I forgot to point out. If the range boundary is not equal to the step, i.e. you have a case of:

```
gen_range(100, 143, 10)
```

the upper boundary should be 143, and not 150, as some answers here would produce, due to `range()` internals.

Comment: Remove the recursion? I'm pretty sure a function call is more expensive than keeping an extra value running in a for-loop.

Comment: Hmm? I might be stupid, but I couldn't come up with a 'for-loop' solution for this one, care to point me in what I am overlooking?

Comment: in pseudo code: `for i = start, i < end, i += step do batch_list.append([i, i + step]) forend`. Seems simple enough, did I miss something?

Comment: Would be cool, if python `for` loops worked that way ;)

Comment: can't you get that result using a `for x in xrange(start,stop,step)` construct?

Comment: Also, do you need to hold the list in its entirety at any given time, or just a subset? Or do you even just need to index a particular element?

Comment: Let's say I need to hold it in its entirety, for the sake of experiment cleanliness :) And no, this is not a homework or anything, it's a part of a tool we're building, just looking for better solutions :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### A really short way:

```
ranges = [(n, min(n+step, stop)) for n in xrange(start, stop, step)]
```

#### More verbose ways:

Perhaps via a generator?

```
def gen_range(start, stop, step):
    current = start
    while current < stop:
        next_current = current + step
        if next_current < stop:
            yield (current, next_current)
        else:
            yield (current, stop)
        current = next_current
```

Calling this function gives you a generator object that will produce each of the tuples in order. You would use it like this:

```
for block in gen_range(100000000,600000000,100):
    print block
```

which would output...

```
(100000000,100000100)
(100000100,100000200)
(100000200,100000300)
...
(599999900,600000000)
```

You could do this even more simply with a generator expression if you're always certain that `stop-start` is an even multiple of the `step`:

```
ranges = ((n, n+step) for n in xrange(start, stop, step))

# Usage
for block in ranges:
    print block
```

Also note that if you want to turn a generator into a list, holding the entirety of the results in memory, you can simply pass it to `list()`:

```
all_ranges = list(gen_range(100000000,600000000,100))
```

Comment: Again, in both cases, with edges that are offset from the step, so, let's say `gen_range(100, 143, 10)` it will produce an interesting sequence having `(140, 150), (140, 143)` as last 2 blocks.

Comment: @favoretti Fixed. Good catch.

Comment: And you know what a freaky part is? This solution is 400ms slower on provided example of 100M to 600M in steps of 100, than the original kludge in my question :)

Comment: @favoretti If you're going through the entire list and/or holding it all in memory, a generator doesn't buy you much (especially for basic Python types like tuples and integers).

Comment: However, see the code-length optimized version I just edited in. It's pretty, at least.

Comment: The short one rocks and it _is_ faster! :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe code-length wise if `(b - a) % c == 0`:

```
def gen_range(a, b, c):
    return [(i, i + c) for i in range(a, b, c)]
```

or

```
def gen_range_2(a, b, c):
    s = range(a, b + c, c)
    return zip(s, s[1:])
```

See http://ideone.com/VhY215

If `(b - a) % c != 0`:

```
def gen_range(a, b, c):
    return [(i, i + c) for i in range(a, b - ((b - a) % c), c)]
```

or

```
def gen_range_2(a, b, c):
    s = range(a, b - ((b - a) % c) + c, c)
    return zip(s, s[1:])
```

See http://ideone.com/i3Pq69

Comment: One problem with this one, is range itself. Point being, if you apply it to `gen_range(100, 143, 10)`, `range` will show 150 as upper boundary, where 143 is actually desirable. Sorry I didn't make it clear in the post, I'll add it to the question.

Comment: @favoretti fixed, or tried to - didn't end up helping the character count, unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

```
In [48]: it=iter(xrange(100,200,10))

In [49]: it1=iter(xrange(110,210,10))

In [50]: [(next(it),next(it1)) for _ in range(10)]
Out[50]: 
[(100, 110),
 (110, 120),
 (120, 130),
 (130, 140),
 (140, 150),
 (150, 160),
 (160, 170),
 (170, 180),
 (180, 190),
 (190, 200)]
```

or using `zip()`:

```
In [55]: it=iter(xrange(100,200,10))

In [56]: it1=iter(xrange(110,210,10))

In [57]: [(x,y) for x,y in zip(it,it1)]
Out[57]: 
[(100, 110),
 (110, 120),
 (120, 130),
 (130, 140),
 (140, 150),
 (150, 160),
 (160, 170),
 (170, 180),
 (180, 190),
 (190, 200)]
```

Comment: I have experimented with `zip()` based approach as well, and albeit not on `xrange` iterators, but on 2 lists, it was about 2x slower than a provided `enumerate()` approach.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I correctly understood the problem, but this can be simply done with a list comprehension:

```
start = 100
stop = 140
step = 10
[ range(s,s+step+1,step) for s in range(start,stop,step)]
```

if you need only to iterate over your list element one at the time, I strongly suggest you to use a generator comprehension instead:

```
res = ( range(s,s+step+1,step) for s in range(start,stop,step))
```

You can iterate over it in a cycle:

```
for range_piece in res:
    do_something with it
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd make it a generator so it could handle huge ranges.

```
def gen_range(start, stop, step):
    a, b = start, start+step
    while b <= stop:
        yield a, b
        a, b = b, b+step

print list(gen_range(100, 140, 10))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with the generator approach, but if you're going to be unpacking the thing into an explicit list, another way to look at it is that you've got a really simple relationship between the elements of your tuple, and all you need to do is range the length properly.

```
def gen_range(start, stop, step):
   items = ((stop-start) // step)
   return [(start+(n*step), start+(n+1)*step) for n in range(items)]
```

The *only* reason I figured it's worth posting this is that my first thought (and hence the comment query) whether or not you could get away with just asking for the nth tuple in the list without having to generate the lot. If you can't, then I wouldn't go down this angle.

Answer (score 1):

I think generator is a good try:

```
def gen_range(start, stop, step):
    while start < stop:
        yield (start, min(start + step, stop))
        start = start + step

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print [x for x in gen_range(100, 143, 10)]
```